# Connect to a MS SQL database using PHP without Microsoft ODBC libraries

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

Microsoft has not released yet its library for Ubuntu 22.04 (msodbcsql18).
So my PHP code does not work anymore:

```
$SERVER = "192.168.2.51";
$DATABASE = "DB_NAME";
$DRIVER = "/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.9.so.1.1";
const USERNAME = "username";
const PASSWORD = "password";

$db = new PDO("odbc:driver=$DRIVER;server=$SERVER;database=$DATABASE", USERNAME, PASSWORD);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

it returns:

> could not find driver

I wonder if there is an alternative method to connect to such a database that uses a different library.
The DB is a SQL Server 19.

Comment: normally a question that asking for a library or tools isn't well regarded. but, is your older driver still there (in that `/opt/microsoft/...`)? also have you tried [sqlsrv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlsrv.php)?

Comment: If you checkout the [guide here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#ubuntu18), you’ll see that 22.04 is not listed, however if you look at the [server](https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/) you’ll find a directory for 22.04

Comment: @ChrisHaas I'm aware of this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407533/microsoft-odbc-v18-is-not-find-by-apt?noredirect=1#comment2446314_1407533

Comment: @BagusTesa, I'm not asking for a specific library, just a workaround to connect to a MS database. Anyway: yes, the old driver is still there, no I didn't try `sqlsrv` because it seems Windows compatible only: https://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlsrv.requirements.php

Comment: Can you try manually installing the deb file?

Comment: @ChrisHaas which debian file? I'm not able to find it

Comment: SQLSRV started a [Linux version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/microsoft-php-drivers-for-sql-server-support-matrix?view=sql-server-ver15#supported-operating-systems) a few years ago, Microsoft has its own docs and they don't seem to care about updating PHP manual. What I don't know if it relies on ODBC under the hood (Windows version does). Plus Ubuntu 22.04 is not listed yet anyway.

Comment: @ChrisHaas there aren't any .deb packages for Ubuntu 22.04 at [Download ODBC Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server). Ubuntu 22.04 is based on Debian 12/Bookworm and there aren't any Debian 12 .deb files there either.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, there's a deb here: https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/22.04/

Comment: @ChrisHaas did you `curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/22.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb > packages-microsoft-prod.deb` and `dpkg --info ./packages-microsoft-prod.deb`? It's a 3,692 byte info package, there's no code or utils included. Microsoft hasn't released anything useful for Ubuntu 22.04... yet.

Comment: I saw that it had some apt/sources entries, and also that https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/prod/dists/jammy/ has binaries, but I didn't verify anything specifically

Answer (score 0):

You can manually download and install the deb file from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15).

It appears to be working for me so far, YMMV.

As an alternative we were previously using the old [pdo_dblib](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php) driver with success.

Comment: I downloaded and installed the Debian package. It placed the new file under `/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql18/lib64/libmsodbcsql-18.0.so.1.1` but still the (updated) code above returns the very same error.

Comment: because on your system it works, would you please add some details about it and how you tested the connection?

Comment: Hey, sorry, I forgot I had notifications turned off. Hopefully you've got it working now. I installed version 17 due to a compatibility issue. I followed the rest of the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac) to install sqlsrv and pdo_sqlsrv. I'm using it to make queries against a database with a custom Drupal module (using the sqlsrv driver module) and all of my queries have worked so far. Maybe it didn't register correctly with unixODBC? Can test with `odbcinst -q -d`?

Comment: Thanks, solved in this way: https://askubuntu.com/a/1409311/1036006